# How to call public boolean equals(Object other)

Tags: java

How would I be able to call this method later? In another method I need to print something if this value returns true, but I don't know how to call this method.

```
public boolean equals(Object other)
{        
 if (this == other)
 {
     return true;
 } else {
     return false;
 }
}
```

Other method (i need to use true or false)

```
public static void main(String[] args){
if (what == true)
{ 
   System.out.print("It is valid")
}
}
```

Comment: `if (a.equals(b))`....

Comment: Same way you call any other method (but since this does the same thing as the default `equals`, it doesn't need to exist).

Comment: You could also call it with null: `a.equals( null )` which will work, but always return `false`.

Comment: It's still pretty unclear. Are you asking how to call a method? Why did you put `if (a.equals(b))` inside your `equals()` method?

Comment: Now it makes no sense in a different way. What are `a` and `b`? It sounds like you misinterpreted Lashane's comment.

Comment: user2357112 already gave you the answer.  Omit the `==` and the `true`, you can test the return value directly with the `if` if it's already `boolean`.  Another way of saying the same thing: `boolean result = a.equals(b); if(result) { /* something */ }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really confusing but you are missing something basic here.  `equals()` is just a method, and you test its return value just like any other method.

In this case, it returns a boolean, which is what the `if` statement wants, hence there is no need for testing `==` to some value.

```
public class MyTest {

    public boolean equals(Object other)
    {        
     if (this==other)
     {
         return true;
     } else {
         return false;
     }
    }

}
```

Other method:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    MyTest test = new MyTest();
    if (test.equals(new MyTest())  // no need for "== true", it's already boolean
       System.out.print("It is valid")
    else
       System.out.print("It is NOT valid")
}
```

Comment: Another method besides "main"?  Just do it the same way.

Comment: Oh I understand now! Thank you very much for clearing that up!